# Button not showing up on simple app written in MarkupKit with nothing but one button

Tags: ios, swift, markupkit

I'm a totally blind developer trying to learn Swift and iOS programming. Since interface builder is not accessible in the latest xcode I'm trying to use MarkupKit to create a UI. I'm attempting to create a simple app with one button which displays an alert. While the view with proper title displays the button does not. Based on the sample I believe I need to set the value of the button to self but am not sure how to do this. Contents of my view.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!-- Button -->
    <?sectionHeaderView?>

        <UIButton style="systemButton" normalTitle="Press Me" onTouchUpInside="showGreeting"/>
```

And my ViewController.swift is

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  markdownUI
//
//  Created by Jared on 3/1/16.
//  Copyright Â© 2016 Jared. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MarkupKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        view = LMViewBuilder.viewWithName("View", owner: self, root: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "MarkupKit Demo"

    }
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    }


    func showGreeting() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Greeting", message: "Hello!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler:nil))

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on my very limited understanding of MarkupKit, the `<?sectionHeaderView?>` is valid only inside `<LMTableView>` sections. Could that be affecting it?

Comment: @NRitH - that's correct, the `sectionHeaderView` PI only works in `LMTableViews` (arbitrary views don't have section headers). @Jared, I'll take a look at your example and see if I can figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me, even with the extraneous `<?sectionHeaderView?>` PI, which is simply ignored by the parser. Make sure you are telling your application which view controller to present when it starts up:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow()

    window!.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())

    window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    window!.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

When the app starts up, you should see a navigation controller containing a single button that says "Press Me". Tapping the button displays the greeting alert.